# Referencing TFS dll's without installing Team Explorer 2010

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, tfs

I'm having a problem where I need to reference TFS dlls in a custom powershell cmdlet at work. (powershell v 1.0).
The dlls are Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

I can't install Team Explorer 2010 on the server though due to some restrictions, this would solve the problem as it comes with the dlls I need.

What I need is a way to register these dlls and allow my cmdlet to reference them. I'm pretty sure I have copied them to the correct path, and I have tried Regasm.exe without success. It says that it has registered, but I keep getting the "missing file or assembly reference" error when I run the cmdlet.

Is it possible for me to reference these dlls?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unblock the DLLs on security tab, then use `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("dir\dllname.dll")`. Maybe you need to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` method.

Comment: Hey man, thanks alot, you have got me on the right path. I think I have opened another can of worms though.